# Can DDD account for strings?

Tags: c++, debugging, solaris, ddd-debugger

I am trying to figure out a problem in my c++ code and have DDD to debug with on a Sun machine.  I am required to use strings per some standard we have.  But whenever DDD encounters a string variable, it always comes up as being empty.  I want to remember having the same trouble using CVD before on an SGI.
Short of re-writing my code to remove string is there anything else I could try/use?

Comment: Do you mean the c++ class 'string' or just strings in general?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++StringClass.html#GDB_STRING)

They solve it by implementing a helper function that can be used by gdb (should also work for DDD as it uses gdb)

Answer (score 1):

```
p variablename.c_str()
```

or

```
display variablename.c_str()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create a wrapper function that prints out your string, by passing it a memory address:

```
void gs(string &s) { cout << s << endl; }
```

and then in gdb:

```
call gs(somevariable)
```

[Reference](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++StringClass.html)